# Subscribe to two PointCloud2 messages using message_filters

Tags: ros-melodic, message-filters, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to synchronize between two PointCloud2 messages, following these [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Example_.28C.2B-.2B-.29-1). But I was not able to compile the following piece of code:

```
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
#include "sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h"


void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& pc1, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& pc2)
{
  // Solve all of perception here...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "point_clouds_node");

  ros::NodeHandle nHandle;

  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> pc_sub_1(nHandle, "sensors/scan_1", 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> pc_sub_2(nHandle, "sensors/scan_2", 1);
  message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> sync(pc_sub_1, pc_sub_2, 10);
  sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

How can I achieve such a thing? Thanks

**Update:** Here's the error msg:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/publisher.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/subscriber.h:38,
                 from /home/user/catkin_ws/src/my_pkg/src/mySubscriber.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::_bi::list2<A1, A2>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = void (*)(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&); A = boost::_bi::rrlist9<const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&>; A1 = boost::arg<1>; A2 = boost::arg<2>]’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1402:50:   required from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(A1&&, A2&&, A3&&, A4&&, A5&&, A6&&, A7&&, A8&&, A9&&) [with A1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&; A2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&; A3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A9 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; R = void; F = void (*)(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&); L = boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> >; boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:833:35:   required from ‘void boost::_bi::list9<A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >; A = boost::_bi::rrlist9<const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&>; A1 = boost::arg<1>; A2 = boost::arg<2>; A3 = boost::arg<3>; A4 = boost::arg<4>; A5 = boost::arg<5>; A6 = boost::arg<6>; A7 = boost::arg<7>; A8 = boost::arg<8>; A9 = boost::arg<9>]’
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1402:50:   required from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(A1&&, A2&&, A3&&, A4&&, A5&&, A6&&, A7&&, A8&&, A9&&) [with A1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&; A2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&; A3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; A9 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; R = boost::_bi::unspecified; F = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >; L = boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> >; boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11:   required from ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker9<FunctionObj, R, T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:925:38:   required from ‘void boost::function9<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:716:7:   required from ‘boost::function9<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>::function9(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1061:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >&; T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&; typename boost::enable_if_c<(! boost::is_integral<Functor>::value), int>::type = int]’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/signal9.h:281:40:   required from ‘message_filters::Connection message_filters::Signal9<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::addCallback(C&) [with C = const boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >; M0 = sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >; M1 = sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >; M2 = message_filters::NullType; M3 = message_filters::NullType; M4 = message_filters::NullType; M5 = message_filters::NullType; M6 = message_filters::NullType; M7 = message_filters::NullType; M8 = message_filters::NullType]’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:310:40:   required from ‘message_filters::Connection message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::registerCallback(const C&) [with C = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/home/user/catkin_ws/src/my_pkg/src/mySubscriber.cpp:20:55:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:319:35: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&’ from expression of type ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >’
         unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361355/subscribe-to-two-pointcloud2-messages-using-message_filters/) by [Martian](https://answers.ros.org/users/38114/martian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2020-09-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-10**:
One change I would make is Changing callback's input arguments to `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr&`. My understanding is that the callbacks should only accept `ConstPtr&` types.

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2020-09-11**:
please post error or console output

**Comment by [Martian](https://answers.ros.org/users/38114/martian/) on 2020-09-11**:
@atas Sorry for the insufficiency, I just added the complete error message as asked for.

**Comment by [Martian](https://answers.ros.org/users/38114/martian/) on 2020-09-11**:
@JackB I actually thought of that too, as in the tutorials, but unfortunately still with same error msg!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

References `!=` pointers.

`const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<..>& != boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<..> >`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martian](https://answers.ros.org/users/38114/martian/) on 2020-09-11**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you so much, that actually worked. Silly me didn't read the error msg appropriately!!